# Django Unable to set widget in form class

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I want to create a form that hides a field.  This works:

```
form_class = modelform_factory( Model, widgets = { 'field1' : forms.HiddenInput() }, exclude = () )
form = form_class()    # field1 is hidden
```

Why doesn't it work when I create the form_class and then set the widgets through its meta class?

```
form_class = modelform_factory( Model, exclude=() )
form_class._meta.widgets = { 'field1' : forms.HiddenInput() }
form = form_class()  # field1 is not hidden in form
```

Comment: Is this `form` related to a `model`? Why not use `ModelForm` instead?

Comment: Yes, I used modelform_factory to generate the form from model

Comment: I believe the `meta` class is used only when you make a `formset` out of an existing `ModelForm`. I can’t find what you tried in the Django docs.

Comment: It's not documented, I just thought that it might work that way -- I guess not.  Thanks!